# What's the route to get from a stored credential in msalcache.bin to an Azure.Core TokenCredential?

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal

I have a number of CLI applications which use AD authorization. To simplify user login, credentials are cached in an *msalcache* file in a known location using code similar to this...

```
  var storageProperties = new StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder(
                ".msalcache.bin", _directory)
                .WithCacheChangedEvent(_config.ClientId)
                .Build();
  _cacheHelper = await MsalCacheHelper.CreateAsync(storageProperties);
  _cacheHelper.VerifyPersistence();
```

Some applications also retrieve secrets from an Azure KeyVault using code similar to this

```
 var client = new SecretClient(vault,
                new ChainedTokenCredential(
                    new ManagedIdentityCredential(), 
                    new AzureCliCredential()
                ));
```

Using [ManagedIdentityCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet) allows the code to operate from within a deployed application.  [AzureCliCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-dotnet) is used to allow the user access from the CLI.  However, as the name implies, it requires the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) module to be installed and for the user to have separately run `az login`.

It seems that there ought to be a way to reuse the stored credentials from the *msalcache* file to create a suitable [TokenCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet) to provide to the `ChainedTokenCredential` constructor.  I.e. I'd like to be able to write something like...

```
var client = new SecretClient(vault,
                new ChainedTokenCredential(
                    new ManagedIdentityCredential(), 
                    new MsalCacheClient(_pathToMsalCacheFile)
                ));
```

Can anyone suggest the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: (not sure about using msal cache) but can you please check if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azure-key-vault-proxy/) can help. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/opnhqy/azureidentity_and_msal/).

Comment: Thanks - your second link is quite revealing.  To be clearer on the architecture, the app is using MSAL to provide authentication to a web API.  In some other contexts the same app wants to fetch some secrets from a key-vault.  I had _hoped_ that by going through the authentication dance to access the API I could then automatically access the key-vault but I'm beginning to wonder if this just not possible (i.e. key-vault requires a different set of tokens)...  Of course, a workaround is to provide user access to KV secrets via a web-api service which itself has a managed id.....